# Copying data from one server table to another server's table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I am having two servers. Both server have one common table.

Table-Name: `ref_state`

```
Column_name          data_Type
------------------------------------
state_id           smallint
country_id            int
state_short_name    nvarchar
state               nvarchar
is_active              bit
last_update      smalldatetime
is_town               bit
```

I want to take one server table data into another server table.

```
select * from ref_states where country_id=2
```

Comment: do you mean server means different sqlserver server or different database in one sql server?

Comment: yes different SQL server server's

Comment: it is one time process or muliple time.

Comment: one time  process  only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

go to---->start choose import and export wizard.
choose a data source window will open
fill all the credentials  like data source server name and 
choose 'use SQL server authentication' and give username and password. 
and then choose database and click next.
then choose destination details as like source.
if u want to copy a table or view u choose 'copy data from one or more tables '
else choose  write a query to specify data to transfer'
in both cases have to check the data matching with the columns are not.with mapping if ok then click on next ofter mapping then click finish.

Answer (score 0):

If it's WAN, then one of the servers must have ip:port or url to connect. If so, you can use Linked Server or even SSIS package.